# Is there a natural connection on $TM$?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

The [Sasaki metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sasaki_metric)  gives a natural way to equip  $TM$ with a Riemannian metric in case $M$ is already equipped with a Riemanian metric. Question: Let $M$ be manifold equipped with an affine connection, is there a known natural way to equip $TM$ with an affine connection ?

Comment: The connection gives a splitting $T(TM)\cong p^*TM\oplus p^*TM$, and you can pull back the connection on both summands to get a connection on $T(TM)$.

Comment: Hmm thats why I hesitated to ask the question on math overflow. I am not familiar with this idea of splitting T(TM) as a direct sum using the connection, where can I read about it  ?

Comment: It's a good question, many people are not familiar with these things. My understanding is the following. Consider a curve $\gamma:I\to TM$ which projects to $c:I\to M$; $\gamma'(0)$ represents a general element of $T(T(M))$ and $\gamma$ can be interpreted as a section of $c^\ast TM$, i.e. as a vector field along $c$. A connection on $M$ defines a connection on $c^\ast TM$, and so you can consider $\nabla_{\partial/\partial t}\gamma$, which will be an element of $T_{c(0)}M$. And $c'(0)$ is another element of $T_{c(0)}M$. This pair of elements is the splitting of $\gamma'(0)$.

Comment: @Amr this is explained very well in Poor's book "Differential Geometric Structures".